# Vue.js - How to show value in vue multi date picker when edit

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-multi-date-picker in my vuejs code

I want to know when I edit the form How to show selected dates in datepicker text.

for example I am using

```
<m-date-picker
    v-model="date"
    :lang="lang"
    :multi="multi"
    :always-display="false"
    :format="formatDate"
    data-parsley-required="true"
    :class="{
        'is-invalid':
            submitted &&
            $v.date.$error
    }"
>
</m-date-picker>

export default {
    name: "newspaper-result",
    components: {
        editor: Editor // <- Important part
    },
    data() {
        return {
            multi: true,
            lang: "en",
            date: [],
            notClassified: true,
            submitted: false
        };
    },
methods: {
        formatDate(date) {
            return date.toLocaleDateString();
        },
}
```

Now when I insert the date in
this.date = date come from db gives error that date.toLocaleDateString(); is not a function

Comment: what do you mean by `when I edit`? Did you add this `data () { return { multi: true, date: [] } }` code to the component?

Comment: what do you mean by `when I edit`?²

Comment: please read this `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask` or down vote

Comment: @DarlanDieterich please check the question now

Comment: your import in main.js or use local with directive?

Comment: I import in main.js

Comment: please check here my sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-date-picker-vuejs-h6z47

Comment: The sampl is fine and same is rnning in my code Now the thing is when I edit the form and I want those date already in that field

Comment: you can edit example in codesandbox with your situation?

Comment: @DarlanDieterich in the ample you given I want to put the dates in result array and that is displayed inthe calendar input field

Comment: The project "vue-multi-date-picker" is has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.  This is one issue, try change the package.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `toLocaleDateString()` function on a string, but strings don't have such function, this is why you are getting the error.

This function needs a properly constructed date object, not a string, so convert it using `new Date()`:

```js
formatDate(date) {
  return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString()
}
```

Comment: this answer doenst fulil my requirement I applied this but didint work as espected